# An apparent contradiction with a limit

Tags: calculus, limits

I have a very stupid doubt.
Let us suppose we have the functions $f(x)=x^3+x^2$ and $g(x)=x^3$. Let us suppose we want to compute the limit $x \rightarrow \infty$ of the difference of those functions. I could compute first the limit
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}x^3(1+1/x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}x^3
\end{equation}
and then the limit
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}x^3.
\end{equation}
Hence
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x)-g(x))=\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)-\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}x^3-\lim_{x\to\infty}x^3=\lim_{x\to\infty}(x^3-x^3)=0.
\end{equation}
However, I could also say that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x)-g(x))=\lim_{x\to\infty}(x^3+x^2-x^3)=\lim_{x\to\infty}x^2=\infty
\end{equation}
So, apparently it seems that there are two different results. Of course I am doing something wrong. Could you illuminate me?

Edit: I forgot that the property does not hold if the limits are $\infty$: $\lim(f-g)\neq\lim f -\lim g$. Hence, if I want the limit of the difference I compute $\lim(f-g)$. If Instead I want the difference of the limits I compute $\lim f - \lim g$. So, it should be okay that we get two different answers, because we are computing two different quantities.

Comment: Neither $g$ nor $f$ has a limit as $x$ tends to infinity. So you can't say anything about those limits. Saying "$f$ tends to infinity" has a meaning but only really by convention – it doesn't mean that there is a real number "infinity" which is the limit of $f$.

Comment: $\lim_{x\to\infty}x^3-\lim_{x\to\infty}x^3$ does not exist. You cannot write it as $\lim_{x\to\infty}(x^3-x^3)$.

Comment: But the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}x^3$ does exist. It is $\infty$. The fact that the limit is infinite is okay and means that the limit exists. The element $l=\infty$ can be defined as an element of the metric space $\bar{\mathbb{R}}=\mathbb{R}\cup\{+\infty,-\infty\}$ (there is also a classical defintion of f going to $\infty$ with epsilons and deltas, in the same spriti of the usual definitiion of finite limit). A limit that does not exists would be instead this one: $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sin x$. Since the limit exists I can apply the property $\lim (f+g)=\lim f + \lim g$

Comment: @RubenCamposDelgado But does your extension to $\bar{\mathbb{R}}=\mathbb{R}\cup\{+\infty,-\infty\}$ also has the property $\lim (f+g)=\lim f + \lim g$?

Comment: Ok, so it seems that that property does not hold if the limits are $\infty$. So $\lim (f-g)\neq\lim f -\lim g$. Hence, if I want the limit of the difference I compute $\lim(f-g)$. If Instead I want the difference of the limits I compute $\lim f - \lim g$

Comment: @Ruben In fact, as your example shows, the property mentioned by Vtand doesn't hold in $\bar{\mathbb R}$: $$\newcommand\i{\infty}\lim_{x\to\i}((f(x)-g(x))=\i,$$ but $$\lim_{x\to\i}f(x)-\lim_{x\to\i}g(x)$$ would "symbolically" be equal to $$\i-\i,$$ which is undefined. Note that defining an extension of arithmetic $$\infty-\infty=k$$ for some real number $k$ (for example $k=0$) just doesn't work: For instance, for compatibility with $>$ you must have $$1+\i=\i,$$ but this violates associativity since $$1+k=1+(\i-\i)=(1+\i)-\i=\i-\i=k,$$ so suddendly you obtain the non-sensical $$\boxed{1=0.}$$

Comment: Thank you, nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Theorem**: If $f$ and $g$ are real-valued functions defined on some real interval $(a, \infty)$, if $L$ and $M$ are real numbers, and if $\lim(f, \infty) = L$ and $\lim(g, \infty) = M$, then $\lim(f - g, \infty)$ exists and equals $L - M$.

This is not the most general statement of this type, but merely given for illustration. The important point is, a theorem is a contract: *If* certain conditions (the hypotheses) are satisfied, *then* some guarantees (the conclusion) hold. If the hypotheses are not met, there are no guarantees. The conclusion may be true, may be false, or may fail to be meaningful.

The issue here, as noted in the comments, is that the hypotheses are not met: To say $\lim(f, \infty) = \infty$, for example, is a special way of saying "$\lim(f, \infty)$ does not exist (is not a real number)." Formal subtraction (applying the theorem) is therefore logically unjustified.

Comment: Sure, I forgot that the theorem does not hold if the limits are infinite. Thanks.

Comment: Just an answer for posterity, since the question may well get found in future searches. :)